# How to make a program installed locally prevail in the PATH?

Tags: linux, path

I have no root privileges in my cluster.
I installed a program that is the newest version of it and put it on the PATH variable.
But, there is, already, the same program with the same name installed for all users, but a very old version.
How can I make this one the first option when calling it?

Just changing the name is no option, otherwise, other program that need this, will search for it, and pick the old one.

Thank you.

Comment: Just put its location to the front in the PATH variable. Or you create an alias like that: `alias myprog="/path/to/myprog "` (Note the trailing blank, it is important, see the documentation for that).

Comment: tried this, did not work

Comment: The alias trick worked! feeling stupid that I did not thought using an alias.

Comment: Both things work. Not sure what the issue with that PATH variable is in your case. Smalls fishy.... Maybe you open a new shell when invoking and recreate the PATH variable?